# Not getting the result

Tags: php

I'm trying to connect to the database, but dont know what is the problem with this one. the code goes like this. Please help I'm very new to the php. :(
db_config.php

```
<?php define('DB_USER', "root");
      define('DB_PASSWORD', "database password");
      define('DB_DATABASE', "ews_app");
      define('DB_SERVER', "Im using the 'drupal' for webhosting should I give server address or localhost");
 ?>
```

**db_connect.php**

```
    <?php

    class DB_CONNECT {

    function __construct() {
        $this->connect();
     echo "<p>server connected</p>";
    }
    function __destruct() {
        $this->close();
    }
    function connect() {

        require_once __DIR__ . '/db_config.php';


        $con = mysql_connect(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD) or die(mysql_error());


        $db = mysql_select_db(DB_DATABASE) or die(mysql_error()) or die(mysql_error());


        return $con;
    }

    function close() {

        mysql_close();
    }

}

?>
```

It should print server connected once it connect to the database. Are there any modification needed on it.

Answer (score 1):

You don't appear to ever be instantiating the object, so the constructor never gets run, so of course no connection is established, so you don't get any output.

Try adding `$connection = new DB_CONNECT()`